# Errors somewhere in code

Tags: java, variables

I'm 100% new to Java and am currently doing a course in it. I'm doing a mock up program that tests a users input against a pre-defined code I.E. a password (The numbers from the program Lost), however I am running into difficulties (see below) any help would be greatly appreciated. The main error I'm getting is with the if else statement...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lost 
{
   public static void main( String[] args ) 
   {
       String  myNumber;
       myNumber = "4815162342" ; 

      // create Scanner to obtain input from command window
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );


      // prompt user for input and obtain value from user
      System.out.print( "Enter numbers..." );


      // if...else is nested

      if ( result == myNumber );
           // if result numbers,
          System.out.print( "...You've just saved the world for now!!" );
      else
          System.out.print( "BOOM!!!!" );


  } // end main
} // end class Lost

 // put notes here:
```

Comment: Your `if`-statement is terminated, your input is never read and your `result` never initialized.. have you thought about trying out an IDE with compiler warnings yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: So you just banged all this out before running it. Build it up bit by bit.

Comment: @weston: Probably not, this seems more like a syntax problem. The `String` comparison is also a problem of course.

Comment: @Keppil OK, well If I could change reason I'd change to close as simple typographical error.

Comment: @c1jericho Take a look at my solution below. You can accept one solution which helps you most by clicking on the hollow tick beside the answer. You get 2 rep in return.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has the following issues :

1. `if ( result == myNumber );` the `;` at the end results in an empty body for the if statement. That's why you get an error for `else` without `if`. Delete the `;`
2. `result` is not defined in your code
3. You are comparing `String` variables with `==`. That will compare if the references are the same. If you want to compare the contents of the `String` use

   ```
   if (result.equals(myNumber))
   ```
4. You seem to be missing the part that reads user input. It will look something like

   ```
   String result = "";
   if (input.hasNextLine())
       result = input.nextLine();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Make changes in your code as

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lost {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String  myNumber;
           myNumber = "4815162342" ; 

          // create Scanner to obtain input from command window

          System.out.print( "Enter numbers..." );

          Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

          String result = input.next();


          // prompt user for input and obtain value from user



          // if...else is nested

          if ( result.equals(myNumber) )
               // if result numbers,
              System.out.print( "...You've just saved the world for now!!" );
          else
              System.out.print( "BOOM!!!!" );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lost 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        String myNumber = "4815162342"; 
        Scanner scn= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter numbers...");
        String result = scn.nextLine();    //receive input with string (Line 10)

        if (result.equals(myNumber))       //compare strings (input vs myNumber)
            System.out.println("...You've just saved the world for now!!");
        else
          System.out.println("BOOM!!!!");
  }
}
```

If you choose to receive the input numbers with integer, you will be using `scn.nextInt()` or `Integer.parseInt(scn.nextLine())` at ***line 10***, and comparison of result against muNumber will be `(result == myNumber)` instead of `result.equals(myNumber)`.

As of now, for your basic understanding, when comparing primitives such as int, you use `==`. When comparing objects and Strings, use `.equals()`.

Comment: Is this code block supposed to be a valid solution for OP's problem? If yes: have you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the semi-colon behind the following line:

`if ( result == myNumber );`

You might want to get used to enclosing single-statement ifs in curly braces as well. I find that it's less error-prone when you need to add multiple statements to such a branch when the braces are already there.